# Simulating the accelerometer event feature in Firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, accelerometer, firefox3.6

I just [downloaded Firefox 3.6 today](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/video/?video=whatsnew-3.6) and I noticed in the list of new features they have [an Orientation API](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/10/orientation-for-firefox/) that can detect the direction that your laptop/computer is tilted.  This is clearly a hardware feature of some sort; So if you don't have the [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/99036/what-kind-of-computers-laptops-support-the-new-orientation-features-of-firefox-3) to do so is there any way of simulating it so that you can test it out on your projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simulate the `MozTransform` with the following code (code borrowed from [Mozilla Orientation Demo 2](http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/demos/orientation/test2.html)):

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

// This will rotate / zoom your document based on the x and y values:

document.body.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(' + (-y * 30) + 'deg) ' + 
                                   'scale(' + (x + 1) + "," + (x + 1)  + ')';
```

If you are building an application based on the Orientation API, you could implement your event listener as follows:

```
function onChangeOrientation(e)
{
    var x = e.x;
    var y = e.y; 
    var z = e.z;

    // Here you may need to standardize the values of x, y and z
    // For example: (-1 * y) on MacBookPro > 5.1.

    processOrientationLogic(x, y, z);
}

// Add the Event Listener for the Accelerometer
window.addEventListener("MozOrientation", onChangeOrientation, true);
```

Then to simulate the orientation event, simply launch `processOrientationLogic()` with your x, y and z values. You could do this from [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or you can also create some sort of three-slider-control on your page that calls this function on every change.